# DataSet.writexml date format issue

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am using the `dataset.writexml` method to generate the XML by executing a query on the MySql database and the query has a date field. When I generate the XML the field value '2012-05-13' is getting converted to as

```
<orderdate>
  <Year>2013</Year> 
  <Month>5</Month> 
  <Day>23</Day> 
  <Hour>0</Hour> 
  <Minute>0</Minute> 
  <Second>0</Second> 
  <Millisecond>0</Millisecond> 
</orderdate>
```

I want this to be formatted as

```
<orderdate>2012-05-13</orderdate>
```

instead of the above format.

Comment: Here is the code                                     strQuery="SELECT e.date orderdate, e.doctorid, u.uid, u.ufname, u.ulname, u.dob, u.sex, p.ethnicity,  p.language,  p.race, u.uname,  u.uemail, u.upphone, p.employerphone, u.umobileno, u.webenabled, p.VoiceEnabled, p.textenabled, ef.id facid FROM tables u,p,e"                                                             DataSet ds = dbHelp.GetDBDataset(strQuery); // gets the dataset                                                    ds.WriteXml(sw, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);

Comment: Is the DB field `e.date` a DateTime (or equivalent) type?  If so, which?  Or is it just a String or something?

Comment: Also, can you simply select it out as you want it, using MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)?

Comment: e.date is a date field in mysql and datetime field in mssql.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see some more code to give you a better answer.

But if you just want it as an entry, convert it to a string:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now
string dateString = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Here is the code                                                   DataSet ds = dbHelp.GetDBDataset(strQuery);    ds.WriteXml(sw, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);